# Click on span in selenium python

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I know people over here tells this is a duplicate one, none of the answers on net helped me. Below is my html code

```
<div class="Headline"><div class="card mt15"><!-- react-empty: 350 --><div class="cardPad"><div class="widgetHead"><span class="widgetTitle">What do you want to wish </span><span class="edit icon">Edit</span></div><div class="widgetCont"><div class="prefill"><div> Good Morning</div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

There is a pencil/pen icon that have class "edit icon" that is beside to "Headline" text on the UI,  I want to click  on that pencil icon and when the pop up opens I need to update it with text "Good morning" . Im trying to achive this using selenium in python.

I tried find by CSS_SELECTORS and find by class_name but im not able to click on it, can someone please advice me on this.

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.Headline > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(2)').click()
```

I tried above code but im getting error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <span class="edit icon">...</span> is not clickable at point (478, 521). Other element would receive the click: <div class="ppContainer">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.135)
```

Comment: How u tried out JavaScript for click like `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)`

Comment: Actually No, i dont know how JS works, so just tyring with dind by class name and css selectors

Comment: You can use same element which you find by css selector `find_element_by_css_selector('.Headline > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(2)')`. Just pass this element in previously mentioned java script

Comment: Thanks Kuldeep, there was a cookies popup at the bottom of the page , so i wasnt able to click on desire button, i handled that and everything worked fine

Answer (score 0):

It’s look like your element is not in window screen and being overlapped by some div. Try javascript click.

```
pen = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()=‘Edit’]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",pen)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",pen)
```

Above will scroll to element and click on it.

Comment: Thanks Rahul , there was a cookies popup at the bottom of the page , so i wasnt able to click on desire button, i handled that and everything worked fine